# Center items in grid layout when not enough data to fill entire row

Tags: css, html, grid-layout

I'm using the new CSS grid layout, basically I'm displaying a series of images, which is fine with six columns, I've gotten that part down, but the content has a variable number, and often times there is not enough content to fill every column, so in the event that there's only say two items in the row, I'd like them to center in the middle two columns. This being a relatively new API though I haven't seen anything like this that I've managed to get working properly. Here is some sample CSS, please excuse my general ignorance if something looks horribly wrong.

```
#result-images{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 260px 260px 260px 260px 260px 260px;
grid-gap: 11px;
grid-column-gap:55px;
background-color: #959595;
border-style:solid;
border-width:3px;
border-color:#FFFFFF;

}

#result-images img{
width:100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #363636;
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Flexbox is actually easier to use to achieve this output. Example below.

```css
#result-images{
display:flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content:center;
align-content:center;
align-items:center;
border: 2px solid black;
max-width:360px;
}

#result-images img{
min-width: 120px;
max-width: 120px;
min-height: 120px;
max-height: 120px;
flex: 0 1 auto
align-self:center;
}
```

```html
<section id="result-images">

<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg">
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg">
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg">
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg">
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.jpg">


</section>
```

1. List item

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I will be using flex in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Center an ***image*** in the area

```css
#result-images {
    border: 2px solid #fffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #959595;
}

#result-images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    ". a a a a ."
    ". a a a a .";
}
img {
  grid-area: a;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result-images">
 <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1018/805106121_ab84d1a216_b.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not solve the problem. Specifically, again, I have six columns and multiple rows, the last row currently only has two items which are displayed under column one and column two, I'd like them to be in the middle, however. There can be a variable number of items in the row with a variable number of rows, but always six columns.

Answer (score 0):

use auto-fit with repeat()

in your case `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 260px)`